# Why is Firebase not running my functions folder (for a node app)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

**I am trying to host a node app on firebase**

The problem is that it keeps timing out when I run a really basic time stamp function.

Here is the firebase.json file:

```js
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/timestamp",
      "function": "app"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the package.json file that is in the functions folder:

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node": "^14.8.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is the index.js in the funtions folder:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/timestamp', (request, response)=>{
    response.send(`${Date.now()}`);
});

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And here is the terminal log when i run firebase locally:

```js
Andrews-iMac:functions test$ firebase serve --only functions,hosting
⚠  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"
i  functions: Watching "/Users/test/Desktop/Git/Deep Technology/deep-technology/functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
[hosting] Rewriting /timestamp to http://localhost:5001/deep-technology/us-central1/app for local Function app
✔  functions[helloWorld]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/deep-technology/us-central1/helloWorld).
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2020:17:32:31 +0000] "GET /timestamp HTTP/1.1" 504 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
[hosting] Rewriting /timestamp to http://localhost:5001/deep-technology/us-central1/app for local Function app
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2020:17:33:50 +0000] "GET /timestamp HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is a screenshot of me running the local host (you can also see the file structure):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out, however, your questions is perfect and I was able to replicate this on my side easily. After few tries, I found it, but it's very small mistake, however such mistakes are hardest to find.

In presented code function in `hosting` in `firebase.json` is different than function exported from `index.js`. So there are 2 solutions:

in `firebase.json` hosting there should be `"function": "helloWorld"`

or

in `index.js` there should be: `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

Both are working well on my side!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I went to the **firebase.json** file and I originally had it as:

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
    }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }]
  }
}
```